# jQuery listen to ko data bound input

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, jquery

I have a component with for a "quantity changer", comprising of an input field and plus/minus buttons. The input and buttons are connected via data-binding on a KO observable. This works as expected.

```
<div class="qty-changer"
    data-bind="scope: 'qty_product_id'"
    data-mage-init='{
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "qty_product_id": {
                    "component": "qtyChange",
                    "defaultQty": 1,
                    "minQty": 1,
                    "maxQty": 999
                }
            }
        }
    }'>
    <span class="product__qty-wrapper">
        <span class="minus"
              title="-1"
              data-bind="click: decreaseQty">-</span>
        <input id="qty_product_id"
               name="qty_product_id"
               data-bind="value: qty"
               value="1"
               type="number"
               size="4"
               class="input-text input-qty"
               maxlength="12" />
        <span class="plus"
              title="+1"
              data-bind="click: increaseQty">+</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({

        defaultQty: 0,
        minQty: 0,
        maxQty: 999999,

        initialize: function () {
            //initialize parent Component
            this._super();
            this.qty = ko.observable(this.defaultQty);
            this.qty.subscribe(this.qtyOnChange, this);
        },

        decreaseQty: function() {
            var newQty = parseInt(this.qty()) - 1;
            if (newQty < this.minQty) {
                newQty = this.minQty;
            }
            this.qty(newQty);
        },

        increaseQty: function() {
            var newQty = parseInt(this.qty()) + 1;
            if (newQty > this.maxQty) {
                newQty = this.maxQty;
            }
            this.qty(newQty);
        },

        qtyOnChange: function (newValue) {
            if (newValue < this.minQty) {
                this.qty(this.minQty);
            }
            if (newValue > this.maxQty) {
                this.qty(this.maxQty);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now I need to react to changes in the value in a completely other part of the site. I tried to listen to change events on the input via jQuery:

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.input-qty').on('change', function(e) {
            alert('test');
        });
    });
});
```

However, the event handler is never executed. In the debugger, I can see that the event is attached, but all events are removed when the KO binding gets active.

My question: Is there a way to add event listeners to an input, that has a data-binding? Or is there a way to directly bind to the `qty` observable via jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after not getting a good solution, I fixed it by sending a custom event:

```
qtyOnChange: function (newValue) {
    if (newValue < this.minQty) {
        this.qty(this.minQty);
    }
    if (newValue > this.maxQty) {
        this.qty(this.maxQty);
    }
    $(document).trigger('qtyChange', [this.elem, this.qty()]);
}
```